# Remove some part of URL using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a URL which will be something like below

```
http://localhost:22306/NESSPATH/VSAT/I-HP-AAMB-ENB-0003_C1//Panaromic//120.jpg
```

I want URL which will be something like this

```
NESSPATH/VSAT/I-HP-AAMB-ENB-0003_C1//Panaromic//120.jpg
```

Here is what I get in variable

```
VSATSaving.PANAROMIC_120 = document.getElementById('ImgPanaromic120').src;
```

how to get that using javascript. Tried with `lastIndexOf` but it is not working

Comment: Where's your [mcve] showing what you've tried?

Comment: @zzzzBov: I tried with `LastIndexOf` but it was always giving me the image name only.

Comment: You said that already, but you haven't included an actual code example, and `lastIndexOf` isn't a good choice for parsing URLs. You need to [do more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/497418).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new [URL object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) and use the `pathname` property to extract the data.

```js
const myUrl = new URL(document.getElementById('ImgPanaromic120').src);

console.log(myUrl.pathname);
```

```html
<img id="ImgPanaromic120" src="http://localhost:22306/NESSPATH/VSAT/I-HP-AAMB-ENB-0003_C1//Panaromic//120.jpg"/>
```

Comment: `myUrl.pathname` giving me undefined

Comment: i tried like this `const myUrl = document.getElementById('ImgPanaromic120').src;

    VSATSaving.PANAROMIC_120 = myUrl.pathname;`

Comment: And where is the `new URL(...)`? Try `const myUrl = new URL(document.getElementById('ImgPanaromic120').src); VSATSaving.PANAROMIC_120 = myUrl.pathname;`

Comment: `const myUrl = new URL(document.getElementById('ImgPanaromic120').src);` it's giving me error as `0x800a01bd - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this action`

Comment: I've updated my answer and used `document.getElementById('ImgPanaromic120').src`. Works fine. Please make sure where the error is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = 'http://localhost:22306/NESSPATH/VSAT/I-HP-AAMB-ENB-0003_C1//Panaromic//120.jpg';
console.log(a.pathname);
```

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.pathname` will give you path.

Comment: you can look here : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_loc_pathname

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use `window.location.pathname` since this is a url.

For other strings, you can use `indexOf`, `split`, `substring` and many of the other string functions.

```js
//example using `split`
var str = "http://localhost:22306/NESSPATH/VSAT/I-HP-AAMB-ENB-0003_C1//Panaromic//120.jpg";
var paths = str.split("http://localhost:22306/")
console.log(paths[1]);
```